# Set Bar values to the center of bar in MPAndroid Bar Chart

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid chart library i want a stacked bar chart to generate Stacked bar chart. I am getting this.

[image: Stacked Bar Graph]

**But i want Like this**

[image: Stack Bar chart i want]

Any help will be highly Appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not possible, check https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/392